# How to draw map road with three.js

Tags: three.js

In 2d canvas, we can draw a line and set its width as a road on map, how can I implement this with Three js in a 3d scene. I have found that Path seemed to be the most approximate to my idea, but I don't know how to use it.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the html5 canvas renderer, you can assign a width to the material -- the parameter is '(material).linewidth' (likewise '.linecap' and '.linejoin') -- so you would usedifferent materails for thinenr or wider road markers